# Adding a WHERE statement refering another table in Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, dynamic, pivot, dynamic-sql

I currently have the following script which is pivoting results from rows into columns. It works a Great, apart from two issues;

1. I have a flag in another table which I want to filter by (basically: `WHERE Table.Stats=YES`). I'd normally do this in a basic query with an inner join followed by that WHERE statement. In the query below, I already have a `WHERE FileSeq=25`, which works, but this criteria I need to get working is calling on a different table.
2. The query is returning a lot of uncessary NULL fields.

   ```
   DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

   SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(col+CAST(rn AS varchar(6)))
               FROM
               (
                 SELECT row_number() over(partition by UID ORDER BY ClassCode) rn
                 FROM dbo.StudentClasses
               ) d
               CROSS APPLY
               (

                 SELECT 'ClassCode', 1
               ) c (col, so)
               GROUP BY col, rn, so
               ORDER BY rn, so
       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
       ).VALUE('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
   ,1,1,'')

   set @query = 'SELECT UID,' + @cols + '
        FROM
        (
           SELECT UID, col+CAST(rn AS varchar(10)) col, VALUE
           FROM
           (
             SELECT UID, classcode,
               row_number() over(partition by UID ORDER BY classcode) rn
             FROM StudentClasses WHERE FileSeq=25
           ) t
   CROSS APPLY
           (
             SELECT ''classcode'', CAST(classcode AS varchar(6))
           ) c (col, VALUE)
       ) x
       PIVOT
       (
           MAX(VALUE)
           for col in (' + @cols + ')
       ) p '
   EXECUTE(@query)
   ```

Any assistance appreciated

Comment: Always include a tag for the primary language you're working with, otherwise your question will not be seen by most people who are knowledgeable about the subject matter. (Also, the language tag usually automatically adds syntax highlighting.)